# Parsing JSON into custom POJO which has Map as one it's class member

Tags: jackson

I have below JSON which I want to parse into below bean classes.

```
{
    "timeStamp": "123123123123",
    "pznFlowFlag": "true",
    "pznRequestFlag": "true",
    "sessionId": "SampleSessionId",
    "ipAddress": "172.148.0.1",
    "offers": [
    {
            "111": {
                "eep" : "44279",
                "spl_ind" : "true"},
            "121": {
                "eep" : "44520",
                "spl_ind" : "false"},
            "333": {
                "eep" : "45419",
                "spl_ind" : "false" }
    }]
}
```

Bean class 1

```
public class DistributedCookieBean {

    @JsonProperty("timeStamp")
    private String timeStamp;

    @JsonProperty("pznFlowFlag")
    private String pznFlowFlag;

    @JsonProperty("pznRequestFlag")
    private String pznRequestFlag;

    @JsonProperty("sessionId")
    private String sessionId;

    @JsonProperty("ipAddress")
    private String ipAddress;

    @JsonProperty("offers")
    private Map<String, OfferCookieBean> offers = new HashMap<String, OfferCookieBean>();

...<setters & getters>
}
```

Bean class 2

```
public class OfferCookieBean {

    @JsonProperty("eep")
    private String eep;

    @JsonProperty("spl_ind")
    private String spl_ind;

...<setters & getters>
}
```

Here I am not able to parse into the these Java POJOs using below code.

jsonObjMapper.readValue(jsonString, DistributedCookieBean.class);

Stacktrace:

org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.Map out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: json.txt; line: 6, column: 31]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:159)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:192)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:134)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:23)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:135)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:221)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:391)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:287)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:1588)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1074)
    at Test.main(Test.java:29)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the property name for the 'offers' field. If it does not help, post the exception stack trace.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the JSON in question. I picked up old JSON.

here is stacktrace added in the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message points to the problem: the `offers` field is declared as a map while in JSON it is an array of maps.

Try to change `Map<String, OfferCookieBean> offers = new HashMap<String, OfferCookieBean>()` to `List<Map<String, OfferCookieBean>> offers;` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But this is kind of Hack we did. What kind of changes I will have to do in JSON for parsing the JSON in Map<String, OfferCookieBean>?

Comment: It's easy to guess: do the opposite - move the map out of the array.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. Thanks a lot!!